# Will the list returned by a stream always be sorted if the input list was sorted?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Assume you have a sorted `List<String> input`. I am wondering if the following `List<String> output` will always be sorted?

```
List<String> output = input.stream
                           .filter(<predicate>)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: in your exact example, order will be preserved, but generally you need to inspect each intermediate operation. things are far more interesting for a parallel stream -when intermediate operations have no order, while terminal one does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a stream from an ordered collection such as lists, arrays or from some generators i.e. Stream.iterate, ranges etc the stream will preserve that order and the results of the stream will be accumulated in the order of the original elements.

So in this case, yes the order is preserved.

Comment: *unless* that order is broken via some intermediate operations, obviously

Comment: @Eugene I’d expect anyone who explicitly calls unordered() to know what that means and what it does, but yes agreed!

Comment: even unordered is not trivial, as it only means get whatever element, by *whatever* for this example `....unordered().findFirst()` returning the *real* first one from the stream source, is more than fine.

Answer (score 2):

The order of the elements in the stream is maintained in the returned list as stated by  [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()) :

> a Collector which collects all the input elements into a List, **in
>   encounter order**